# Sorting an array of objects depending on object attribute

Tags: php

I have an array composed of objects.

```
[
    {
        "name" => "First",
        "order" => 5
    },
    {
        "name" => "Second",
        "order" => 3
    },
    {
        "name" => "Third",
        "order" => 9
]
```

How can I order it by ascending "order" value ?

I should get :

```
[
    {
        "name" => "Second",
        "order" => 3
    },
    {
        "name" => "First",
        "order" => 5
    },
    {
        "name" => "Third",
        "order" => 9
];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort multidimensional Array by Value (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2)

Comment: Please see [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17364127/476)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the PHP `usort()` function like this for arrays:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){return $a["order"]-$b["order"];});
```

or for objects:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){return $a->order-$b->order;});
```

Here's the PHP reference: [usort()](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: @Ping - I've added an extra example: same idea, just slightly different syntax for objects.

Comment: Thanks, it works ! This helped me a lot to learn about how sorting works.